# Scrolling inside React Material Container Component is not smooth

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a component rendering a few children components.
I am running the app on mobile browser Chrome and Safari and also as a PWA on iOS.

When I render that component inside a full screen material dialog the scroll is fine smooth and fast as expected.

However, when i render that same component inside a Container component (see following code), the scrolling is slow and not smooth.
The behaviour is exactly same as described in the dialog API page (Scrolling long content
section), but i can't see any similar property (scroll=paper or body) on Container component API.
Any thoughts? What am i doing wrong here?

Styles object:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    height: '100vh',
    overflow: 'auto',
  },
  container: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(4),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(4),
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
}
```

and the function where I render the component with the weird scroll issue:

```
<main className={classes.content}>
  <Container maxWidth="lg" className={classes.container}>
       <MyComponent/>
  </Container>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

`WebkitOverflowScrolling: 'touch'` did the job after all.